# Windows console app stops printing when I switch to Edge

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, wchar-t

I have to write a console app to log the active window PID, text length and text.

It works except when I switch to Edge. The execution doesn't stop, but only the PID and text length get printed to the screen.

Please help, I don't know what else to try.

[image: Console app output showind PID, window text length and window text]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

int main()
{
    // Use environment's default locale for char type
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    std::cout << "Hello é World!\n";

    while (1)
    {
        // Get foreground window
        HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (!hwnd) continue;

        // Get window process ID
        DWORD pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        if (pid) std::cout << "pid " << pid << " ";

        // Get window text length
        int len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);

        // Get window text
        WCHAR* text = new WCHAR[len + 1];
        std::cout << "len " << GetWindowText(hwnd, text, len + 1) << " ";
        //if (!text) continue; // not skipping! so text NOT null
        std::wcout << "text " << text;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        text = NULL;
        
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are leaking memory but that should take a long time to exhaust all of the memory you have available to your process.

Comment: A window does not have to have window text.

Comment: There is no way for the code provided to produce the output provided. Please show the *real* code that matches the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading this from the future, here's what I found out:

**TL;DR**: Unicode char 8203 wasn't representable in the console codepage, which caused `std::wcout` to fail. The solution is to check for `std::wcout.fail()` and if `true` call `std::wcout.clear()`.

Here's how I got to the bottom of it.

I started suspecting it had something to do with `std::wcout` because the following code would keep printing even when I switched to Microsoft Edge (and switched tabs within it):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

int main()
{
    // Use environment's default locale for char type
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    while (1)
    {
        // Get foreground window
        HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (!hwnd) continue;

        // Get window process ID
        DWORD pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        std::cout << "pid " << pid << " ";

        // Get window text length
        int len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);

        // Get window text
        WCHAR* text = new WCHAR[len + 1];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, text, len + 1);
        std::cout << "text " << text << std::endl;

        text = NULL;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Console app output using std::cout for text line]

Where:

- PID `3892` - ConsoleApplication1.exe
- PID `3144` - Visual Studio Code
- PID `9812` - Slack
- PID `8772` - Microsoft Edge - with tabs switched during execution (same PID)

The following code, however, would stop printing the `text ...` line but *keep* printing the `pid ...` line when I switched to Edge (and switched tabs within it):

```cpp
// ...
std::wcout << "text " << text << std::endl; // switched 'cout' with 'wcout'
// ...
```

[image: Console app output using std::wcout for text line]

Where:

- PID `424` - ConsoleApplication1.exe
- PIDs `3144`, `9812` and `8772` same as before

Also, if I switched both `pid ...` and `text ...` lines to `wcout`, then the console output would completely hang as soon as I switched to Edge, clearly showing that the `wcout` stream had failed:

```cpp
// ...
std::wcout << "pid " << pid << " "; // switched 'cout' with 'wcout'
// ...
std::wcout << "text " << text << std::endl; // same
// ...
```

[image: Console output using std::wcout for both PID and text lines]

Where:

- PID `13584` - ConsoleApplication1.exe
- PIDs `3144`, `9812` and `8772` same as before

Now I needed to know *what* was causing `wcout` to fail. Per the console outputs above, `wcout` seemed to fail right after the `t` in "Microsoft". Invisible faulty char, maybe? So I tweaked the code once more to print both the char and its code:

```cpp
// ...
// std::wcout << "text " << text << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(text); i++) std::cout << (char)text[i] << " (" << (int)text[i] << ")\n";
```

[image: Console output showing hidden Unicode char 8203]

As expected, there was an invisible char right after the `t` in Microsoft: [Unicode character 8203](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). Now, finally knowing *what* to throw on Google (a.k.a. "wcout fail unicode 8203"), I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950412/c-cant-get-wcout-to-print-unicode-and-leave-cout-working) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94eec320-3874-4067-b31e-31d2e3703acf/vs2005-console-unicode-wcout-fails) pivotal answers.

Specifically, the code from [@dev7060's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565171/7441775) was the litmus test I needed (here modified):

```cpp
std::wcout << "abc " << L'\u200b' << " defg" << std::endl; // L'\u200b' is unicode char 8203
if (std::wcout.fail()) {
    std::cout << "\nConversion didn't succeed\n";
    std::wcout << "This statement has no effect on the console";
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wcout << "hello world from wcout! \n";
}
std::cout << "hello world from cout! \n";
std::wcout << "hello world from wcout again! \n";
```

[image: Console output showing that wcout fails]

The solution (so far) is the one below.

```cpp
// std::wcout << "text " << text << std::endl;
std::wcout << "text " << text;
if (std::wcout.fail()) std::wcout.clear();
std::cout << std::endl;
```

**EDIT**: found a new (better?) solution that doesn't involve checking `std::wcout.fail()` and calling `std::wcout.clear()`:

**TL;DR**: use `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8")` or (in my case) `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "pt_BR.UTF8")`.

I wanted to figure out why the default environment locale (`setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`) wasn't working, so I devised the following little experiment:

```cpp
std::cout << "default locale " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << std::endl;
std::cout << "default console output code page " << GetConsoleOutputCP() << std::endl;

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "pt_BR.UTF8"); // 'method' column from table below
// SetConsoleOutputCP(850)

std::cout << "new locale " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << std::endl;
std::cout << "new console output code page " << GetConsoleOutputCP() << std::endl;
```

| Method | Default locale | Default CP | New locale | New CP | `wcout` fail? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` | C | 850 | Portuguese_Brazil.1252 | 850 | Yes |
| `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8")` | C | 850 | en_US.UTF8 | 850 | No |
| `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "pt_BR.UTF8")` | C | 850 | pt_BR.UTF8 | 850 | No |
| `SetConsoleOutputCP(850)` OEM Multilingual Latin 1; Western European (DOS) | C | 850 | C | 850 | Yes |
| `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows) | C | 850 | C | 1252 | Yes |
| `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` Unicode (UTF-8) | C | 850 | C | 65001 | Yes |

In my computer (Windows 10 x86-64), the constants `CP_WINANSI` and `CP_WINUNICODE` map to `850` and `CP_UTF8` to `65001`.

Recommended reading:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages